# Change DPI in Windows 8(.1) below 100%

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, dpi, scaling

I want to make all of the UI smaller than possible, because I am running 3 27" Monitors with 1080p resolution and am hoping to get a little more screen real estate out of it. So I have played around a bit in the registry with several occurances of LogPixels by changing to 81, the correct DPI for my screen, but they all reset to the default 96 DPI. I am wondering, if there is something I am missing here. Any help is greatly appreciated.